# How to unscrew this spigot?

Tags: plumbing, leak, hose, copper-tubing, spigot

(From my earlier posts, you may have learned that I had several different bibs cause several different floods in different parts of my house. Each instance posed its own unique challenges. This is a post about spigot number three.)

The following picture shows the spigot from the inside though an access hole:

[image]

It looks to me like I should be able to screw the spigot out but I wasn't able to do it due to resistance and I gave up for fear of causing greater damage. Am I correct that I should be able to screw the spigot out and, if so, are there some safe tricks for loosening the connection?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the spigot above to help us understand the total connections in these joints.

Comment: It appears to me that the copper is sweated inside of the threaded end. It **may** be that the Unit had the option of threading into a female fitting or having the option of accepting 3/4 copper pipe on the inside to be soldered. I am not sure which one. The threads are brass not copper so it seems to be the later, if the the treads were copper it would be the former.

Answer (score 1):

A pipe wrench on the inside on this side of the threads to hold the indoor plumbing in position and a pipe wrench on the outside to unscrew the spigot should do it.

It doesn't look like there's any thread tape in there, though, so it might be rough going.

Additionally, it looks like they sleeved the copper pipe in something else to get it through the wall, which is good, but if that's steel, there could be galvanic corrosion holding the copper to the steel.